# For $n >2$, establish the inequality $\phi(n^2)+\phi((n+1)^2) \leq 2n^2$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

For $n >2$, establish the inequality $\phi(n^2)+\phi((n+1)^2) \leq 2n^2$

I have proven the result ' If $n$ is composite then $\phi(n) \leq n - \sqrt{n}$.

Since both $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ are composite, by using the result above , we obtain $\phi(n^2)+\phi((n+1)^2) \leq n^2-n+(n+1)^2-(n+1)=2n^2$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: How to prove $\phi(n)\le n-\sqrt{n}$ if $n$ is composite?

Comment: By using another result ' If $n$ is composite and $p_1$ is the smallest prime of $n$, then $p_1 \leq \sqrt{n}$'

Comment: You can omit the restriction $n>2,\;$ because for $n=2$ you have $\phi(4)+\phi(9)=2+6=8 \le 2\times 2^2$

Comment: yeah, this is what I think also. But I think I better don modify the question since this is a question from a book

Answer (score 2):

The proof is correct, if the earlier result has been proved carefully. However, there is no need to appeal to an earlier result.

Let $m\gt 1$. Then the $m$ numbers $m, 2m, 3m, \dots,m^2$ are **not** relatively prime to $m^2$, and therefore $\varphi(m^2)\le m^2-m$.

It follows, precisely as you wrote, that
$$\varphi(n^2)+\varphi((n+1)^2)\le n^2-n+(n+1)^2-(n+1)=2n^2.$$